# Notepad++ NppFTP Connecting [SFTP] Connection failed : Socket error: disconnected

Tags: ssh, notepad++, sftp

I connect to the server with ssh turnnel.

```
ssh middleHost -L 12345:desHost:22
```

**The server is FreeBSD.(OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8y)**
It work **successfully** when using sftp in terminal

```
sftp -oPort=12345 localhost
```

But it does **not** work in nppFTP.

When I try and connect using NppFTP I get the following output:

```
Connecting
[SFTP] Connection failed : Socket error: disconnected 
Unable to connect
Disconnected
```

I have tried different NppFTP version ,but invalid.

By the way, another FreeBSD server (OpenSSH_7.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1a-freebsd) on the same subnet can connect successfully on NppFTP.